# c# how do i get check if a selected item in a listbox has changed. ?

Tags: c#, selecteditem

i understand listbox.selectedItem will get me the current item thats seletected in a listbox... how do i get if the current item has been changed. so i want to know if the user's selection has changed from what it was to a different item.

Comment: Is this MVC or Webforms ? The Implementation is different depending.

Comment: Read up on events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to the SelectedIndexChanged  event like this:

```
this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

The listener is:

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Add code in the listener above to react to the event.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event, this is `Windows.Forms`, naturally.